Deterministic Physics - Same Constants produce different results
TLDR; Rapier is a deterministic physics engine and I'm using the same initial variables to drop ball however still get different results.
This could be because of the react three fiber environment.
Github repo:
https://github.com/IbrahimSam96/plinko/pulls
I have a world where I drop balls on a set of pins
Balls drop from the same position using the SAME properties.
However balls don't follow the same path. All pins have the same properties too! Not sure what's causing the balls to take different paths even tho all constants are unchanged.
Ball

<RigidBody
  ref={rigidbody}
  type="dynamic"
  restitution={0.5}
  colliders="ball"
  position={[position.x, position.y, position.z]}
  gravityScale={2.5}
  userData={{
    type: "ball",
    id: ballId,
  }}
  collisionGroups={-1}
  activeCollisionTypes={2}
  onCollisionEnter={(e: CollisionEnterPayload) => {
    if (e.rigidBodyObject?.userData.type === "pin") {
      console.log("Pin collision");
    }

    if (e.rigidBodyObject?.userData.type === "ball") {

    }

  }}
>

Pins
          <RigidBody
            name={`pin-${i}`}
            key={`pin-${i}-${j}`}
            type="fixed"
            colliders="ball"
            collisionGroups={-1}
            position={[pinY, pinX, pinZ]}
            userData={{
              type: "pin",
            }}
          >
            <mesh rotation={[0, 0, 0]}>
              <sphereGeometry args={[pinRadius, 64, 64]} />
              <meshStandardMaterial color="white" />
            </mesh>
          </RigidBody>

